# Method must return type int

Tags: java, return-type

I am trying to do the addition by calling a non-static method in static using dot operator. But I am getting this error: "This method must return a result of type int".

```
class Hello1 {
    int pluss(int...v) {
        int plus=0;
        for(int x :v) {
            plus=plus+x;
            System.out.println(plus);
            return plus;            
        }
    }
}

public class Addition {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        Hello1 h1=new Hello1();
        h1.pluss(3,7,9,10);
    }
}
```

Comment: Close the brace you opened after `for`!

Comment: I'm not sure why this question is getting down-voted. While it may seem like a "stupid" question to some of you it is NOT a poorly worded question. There is an honest issue and code to back it up. This is precisely what this site is here for. Please consider your reasoning for down-votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put the return inside the for loop!

Change this:

```
int pluss(int...v){
  int plus=0;
  for(int x :v)
  {
    plus=plus+x;
    System.out.println(plus);
    return plus;            
  }
}
```

To this:

```
int pluss(int...v){
  int plus=0;
  for(int x :v)
    plus=plus+x;
  System.out.println(plus);
  return plus;            
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem of static or non static method. you can do it you are actually creating an object in it.

**`This method must return a result of type int`**

means you missed the return statement at the end body of method.

```
int plus(int..v){
//do whatever
//end
return plus
}
```

use `int result = h1.pluss(3,7,9,10);` to recieve

Answer (score 0):

Problem with not closing the curly braces in place, try this..

```
class Hello1 {
   int pluss(int...v){
     int plus=0;
     for(int x :v){
     plus=plus+x;
     System.out.println(plus);
     }
     return plus;            

}}

public class Addition{
public static void main(String args[]) {
Hello1 h1=new Hello1();
h1.pluss(3,7,9,10);
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You `return` in the first iteration of your `for` loop, which is probably not what you meant to do - move the `return` out of it:

```
int pluss(int...v) {
     int plus=0;
     for (int x :v) {
         plus=plus+x;
         System.out.println(plus);
    }
    return plus;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The return statement should be outside the for block like this...Check out the below code, it should work fine.

```
  class Hello1
{
    int pluss(int... v)
    {
        int plus = 0;
        for (int x : v)
        {
            plus = plus + x;
            System.out.println(plus);
        }
        return plus;
    }
}

public class Addition
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Hello1 h1 = new Hello1();
        h1.pluss(3, 7, 9, 10);
    }
}
```